# 9.1 Powershell Install Solr Connection Issue

Tags: solr, sitecore-install-framework

I am running the XP1-SingleDevloper.ps1 and it is choking when trying to connect to the solr url. If I hit https://solr:8983/solr in a browser it comes up just fine. Thoughts on why it isn't able to connect?

```
[------------------------------ XConnectSolr_StartSolr : ManageService ---------------------------------------]
[XConnectSolr_StartSolr]:[Updating] Solr-7.6.0

Status   Name               DisplayName                           
------   ----               -----------                           
Running  solr-7.6.0         Solr-7.6.0                            



[------------------------ XConnectSolr_CreateCores [1] : ManageSolrCore --------------------------------------]
[XConnectSolr_CreateCores [1]]:[Requesting] https://solr:8983/solr
WARNING: [1/5] Request Failed: Unable to connect to the remote server
[XConnectSolr_CreateCores [1]]:[Requesting] https://solr:8983/solr
WARNING: [2/5] Request Failed: Unable to connect to the remote server
[XConnectSolr_CreateCores [1]]:[Requesting] https://solr:8983/solr
WARNING: [3/5] Request Failed: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
[XConnectSolr_CreateCores [1]]:[Requesting] https://solr:8983/solr
WARNING: [4/5] Request Failed: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
[XConnectSolr_CreateCores [1]]:[Requesting] https://solr:8983/solr
WARNING: [5/5] Request Failed: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Could not complete request for https://solr:8983/solr - The request was 
aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

Comment: First thing is that is the wrong version of solr for 9.1. It needs 7.7.2. Also is that solr server on the same box or a remote box? Looks like a very issue with solr. Like the self signed cert is not in the trusted store.

Comment: version 7.2.1 version worked, thanks Chris

Comment: I just noticed that I wrote to wrong version number. Nice catch. 7.2.1 is right. Glad to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who comes in on this error message. Sitecore 9.1 requires SOLR version 7.2.1. Using another version will have adverse side effects.

Per https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897

- 8.2 - 6.6.2
- 9.0 - 6.6.2
- 9.1 - 7.2.1

Answer (score 5):

Apart from what Chris mentioned, the error is indicative of TLS version problem. So use this command in powershell before you run the SIF install script.

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

You can find this above solution mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618766/powershell-invoke-webrequest-fails-with-ssl-tls-secure-channel

Answer (score 1):

This error came for me, even though I used Solr version 7.2.1 for installing Sitecore 9.1.1 instance.

**The problem was that the Solr cores were already been created with the same sitecore instance name that I now tried to install**. You can check this in the [Solr Cores URL](https://solr:8984/solr/#/~cores) (Replace port number 8984 with your port number in this URL). For example, if there is a core already with the name **sc911_master_index** and when we attempt to install a new sitecore instance again with the instance name as **sc911**, then also you will get the same error as below:

> Install-SitecoreConfiguration : could not complete request for https://solr:8984/solr

**SOLUTION:**

1. Either **change the sitecore instance name that you want to install**
2. Or, **UNLOAD the solr cores** (with that same instance name that you're now trying to install) from the [Solr Cores URL](https://solr:8984/solr/#/~cores) . You can do this by clicking on each core and then clicking the Unload button.

In my case, I unloaded the cores and then tried to run the installation script again, now this error is resolved.